# PHP regex remove prepend content before dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have in PHP an array string which contain stuff like this:

```
$a = array(
  array('inner' => 'N.person = P.id'),
  array('inner' => 'L.person = P.id'),
  array('left' => 'A.person = P.id AND A.excluded IS NULL')
);
```

And I want to inform primary key `P.id` and remove all alias from sql resulting in something like this:

```
$x = someFunctionThatSanitizeSQL('P.id', $a);
```

print_r on `$x` result:

```
array(
  array('inner' => 'person = :pk'),
  array('inner' => 'person = :pk'),
  array('left' => 'person = :pk AND excluded IS NULL')
);
```

Thanks in advance

@edit: miss a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a `str_replace($pkreplace, ':pk', $mystring);`, the regex I think you're looking for is something like:

```
/(?=(^|\w))[A-Z0-9_-]+\./
```

For example, to clean out each string, you can do

```
preg_replace('/(?=(^|\w))[A-Z0-9_-]+\./i', '', $mystring);
```

However, if you are removing the `A.`, `L.`, etc., there may be other issues with your query due to the values no longer being under the database tables and possibly causing ambiguous value errors. Are you certain this is the behavior you want in your queries?

**EDIT**

A final implementation of your function would look something like (assuming you need arrays):

```
function someFunctionThatSanitizeSQL($pkreplace, $dataarray) {
  if (!is_array($dataarray))
    return null;
  $retval = array();
  foreach ($dataarray as $key => & $curentry) {
    $curstring = str_replace($pkreplace, ':pk', $curentry);
    $curstring = preg_replace('/(?=(^|\w))[A-Z0-9_-]+\./i', '', $curstring);
    $retval[$key] = $curstring;
  }
  return $retval;
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure about this behavior! Because each query will be isolated in your scope. I will implement your regex. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Your regex fits like a glove